# Eclipse Display Window doesn't work I can't run anything there

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, execute

Eclipse Display Window doesn't work I can't run anything there.

For example I am trying to do this in the Display view window:

```
  System.out.println("test")
```

But nothing happens, and when I looked in Eclipse documentationa and in the internet I found that the j icon on the upper right corner of the Display window should be active after I highlight the line of code or I can right click after I highlight the code and see the option to execute the code. but nothing is working.

Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out in the meantime why Debug view is disabled?

Answer (score 3):

Try highlighting the text that you typed into the display window. You might be able to execute it once you do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Display` is used only when the code is being debugged. Put a `Breakpoint` in the code and while the process stops there, use Display to execute your code. It must work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `Consol Window` is not opened in your eclipse. Just follow this steps,

- Go to Window Menu
- Select Show View
- Select Consol ( or shortcut key is Alt+Shift+ Q C )

Comment: I do have Consol window open. Not sure what that has to do with the display window.

Comment: Am I missing something here? All I want is how to run a single line code in the Display window. from my reading on the net there is two ways:  1- highlight then select execute  (I did that but there is no execute option  2- highlight and click on the "j" icon on the right cornder of the Display window but that is inactive. I can't click it.    Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: well i guess better you post the whole code, it may help us to find the problem.

Comment: There is no code. I am simply trying to use the Display window to try a command. like System.out.println("test") that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the command like:

`System.out.println("test")`

and press `Ctrl+U` or `right click` on highlighted text and select execute. It will work.